# What is best strategy to reduce number of javascript files in a framework?

Tags: javascript, performance, architecture, frameworks

I am transferring a PHP framework to JavaScript. In PHP, I have one file per class and so when transferring it over, I am also creating one file per JavaScript class.

However, unlike with PHP, with so many JavaScript files, this will reduce the loading time of my page (I plan to have 30+ classes).

I like to have one class per page simply because when developing it is easier to navigate around my framework.

**What is the best approach to keep this ease of development yet not have so many javascript files that the HTML page has to load?**

[image]

Comment: You can have a PHP page that reads and aggregates the js, then serves it all back to the browser in a single request.

Comment: A good example of this is how TinyMCE implements its [compressors](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php#compressors).  These have a good balance of development structure/flexibility and production performance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are server-side tools that allow you to automatically combine JavaScript/CSS files into one HTTP request.

e.g.

- [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

You could also do this manually when bringing code into production. However I assume that's not something that you would want to do with 30+ files (however for people with only a few, this is a relatively simple solution).

You should make sure all of your JS files are packed/minified to make their file size as small as possible. And also make sure your server is gzip'ing everything so the data it's sending is compressed.

Finally, you should make sure these types of files are cached properly by the browser. You can easily accomplish this by adding a version number to the end of these files and changing the expires header to be far into hte future.

Comment: I hope that doesn't strip license headers.